# Why application hangs when using ReverseProxy?

Tags: http, go, proxy

I'm working on application with reverse proxy and built-in load balance.

When I do high load benchmarks my application hangs on with timeouts being returned to benchmarking tool.

I reproduced this behaviour with minimal code below.

`proxy.go` file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "time"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Pong")
}

func newMux() *http.ServeMux {
    serverURL, _ := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(serverURL)
    sm := http.NewServeMux()
    sm.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    sm.HandleFunc("/proxy", proxy.ServeHTTP)
    return sm
}

func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:         ":1447",
        Handler:      newMux(),
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

`backend.go` file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func newMux() *http.ServeMux {
    sm := http.NewServeMux()
    sm.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    return sm
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello")
}

func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:         ":5000",
        Handler:      newMux(),
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

I do benchmarks with [wrk2 tool](https://github.com/giltene/wrk2) using this command:

```
wrk2 -t12 -c100 -d30s -R20000 http://127.0.0.1:1447/
```

Steps applied to confirm the problem:

1. Compile and start `backend.go` on `5000` port
2. Run `wrk2 -t12 -c100 -d30s -R20000 http://127.0.0.1:5000/` to test naked backend with 20k RPS for 30 seconds long
3. After 30 seconds wrk2 shows these stats `597996 requests in 30.00s, 68.44MB read`
4. Compile and start `proxy.go` on `1447` port
5. Run `wrk2 -t12 -c100 -d30s -R20000 http://127.0.0.1:1447/proxy` to proxy requests to backend with 20k RPS for 30 seconds long
6. After 30 seconds wrk2 shows these stats `33699 requests in 30.06s, 3.89MB read; Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 960`

I can't understand this behaviour – why running benchmark straight to `backend.go` is ok without any timeouts, but proxying requests through ReverseProxy return almost ~94% of timeouts?

Benchmarking on a single MacBook Pro mid 2013 with 8gb RAM and 2.6 GHz intel Core i5.
Current `ulimit` settings:

```
> ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 8192
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1392
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Comment: If I'm reading the output correctly, it looks like 960 timeouts out of 33699 requests, which is 2.8% requests timed out, which means you're testing just past failure, which is expected. You haven't changed any options in the backend transport, so I imagine you're running out of ports from opening and closing connections too quickly.

Comment: @JimB Oh, I see. Could I ask you to point on what potentially could be changed in the backend `Transport{}` to prevent this situation? At least maybe some common things, so that I can search for info myself.

Comment: The first thing I would try is adding `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` to make it high enough to match your expected level of concurrency.